# can't reset form input using ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to reset input value using ng-click to add it's value to a $scope var then reset the input value

here is my html

```
<form ng-controller="questionsCTRL" class="ui large form" name="questionForm" ng-submit="addSurvey(questionForm)" novalidate>

<div class="ui segment" id="quest-answers">


  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Add New Answer</label>
      <div class="ui action input">
        <input type="text" required name="answers" ng-model="answers"
        ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" placeholder="answer...">
        <button type="button"
        ng-click="addAnswer(questionForm.answers.$viewValue)"
        ng-disabled="questionForm.answers.$invalid"
        class="ui teal right labeled icon button">
        <i class="add icon"></i>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
    <small ng-show="questionForm.answers.$invalid" class="ui meta teal">Answers is required</small>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="eleven wide column">

        <div class="field">
          <div class="ui  attached segment" ng-repeat="answer in answerGroup">
            {{answer.text}}
            <a href class="ui right floated link"><i class="circular delete icon"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and this is controller content

```
UIASSIGN1.controller('questionsCTRL', function($scope , $rootScope , $state, $stateParams , $http ) {
            // #dummy controller
      $rootScope.sectorName       = 'Questions';
      var _SID                    = $stateParams.id;
      $scope.answerGroup          = [];

      $http.get("api/survey/survey.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        var surveyArray = response.data;
        $scope.surveyArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < surveyArray.length; i++) {
          var thisItem  = surveyArray[i];
          var thisElm   = {name:thisItem.name,value:parseInt(thisItem._id)};
          $scope.surveyArray.push(thisElm)
        }

      });

      $scope.addAnswer = function(answer){
          var inArray = {
            text : answer
          };
          $scope.answerGroup.push(inArray);
          $scope.questionForm.answers = {};
      }
});
```

this ng-click adds value to $scope.userGroups but it doesn't reset the form input value only resets the $scope.questionForm.answers value to {}

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are displaying the value of `$scope.questionForm.answers` in your HTML. Perhaps you mean to change `$scope.answerGroup` or `$scope.answers`?

Comment: `<input type="text" required name="answers" ng-model="answers"
        ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" placeholder="answer...">` is the input where `$scope.questionForm.answers` value comes from

Comment: Then set `$scope.answers = ""`.

Comment: I want to reset the input value `<input value="" `

Comment: `$scope.answers ` holds the answers added by the input

Comment: I want to reset the input itself after adding new answer

Comment: There is only a single input in your form which is `<input type="text" required name="answers" ng-model="answers"
        ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" placeholder="answer...">` The `ng-model="answers"` means the value of the `input` element is `$scope.answers`. If you don't want to reset that input element then you are not showing all your HTML, what are the other input elements that you want to reset?

Comment: well thank you Spencer

Comment: i tried `$scope.answers = "";` and it work but can you please explain what's the difference bettwen `$scope.answers = "";` and `$scope.questionForm.answers` in this case

Comment: The reason is that the `ng-model="answers"` on your input element means to bind the value `answers` to that be that value of that input element. Hence why `$scope.answers = ""` will reset it. I'll add in an answer to explain it better. The `$scope.questionForm.answers` is what you are using as the input value for the parameter of that function and is what defined the `ng-show` and `ng-disable` in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments the value of `$scope.answer` is mapped to this element:

```
    <input type="text" required name="answers" ng-model="answers"
    ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" placeholder="answer...">
```

The `ng-model="answers"` means to define a variable called `answers` in the scope. Then in angular you can access it with `$scope.answers`, that is why:

```
$scope.answers = "";
```

Will reset the input element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Define the answer on the scope

```
$scope.theAnswer = '';
```

Set this as your ngModel for the input field:

```
ng-model="theAnswer"
```

Simplify your ng-click like this and add the answer to the array directly in the controller and then cleanup the answer:

```
ng-click="addAnswer()"

$scope.addAnswer = function(){
      var inArray = {
        text : $scope.theAnswer
      };
      $scope.answerGroup.push(inArray);
      $scope.theAnswer = '';
  }
```